# How do i return user input from my HTML form in a way that i can pass the return to another function?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

Apologies if this is already covered... I'm trying to pass information from a basic text input form and then parse that information using another couple functions.  I'm not able to figure out how to return the information from the function in the onClick property to pass it into another function.

```js
function getBulletAction(element) {
  
 return element[0].value;
  
 }

// why can't i store this in a variable outside of the function???
let valueFrmForm = getBulletAction(document.getElementById("frmForm"));

document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = valueFrmForm;

  
  
//I want to pass the value returned from getBulletAction() to getAction() which will change the user input to lowercase characters.
function getAction(OutOfTheFunction){
 
 
 let action = userInput.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US');
 
 return action;
 
}
```

```html
<form name="bulletForm" id="frmForm">
Write the action of your bullet:<br>
 <input type="text" name="bulletAction" value="" style="width: 30%;"/>
 <input type="button" name="submitType" value="Submit" onClick="getBulletAction(this.parentElement)" />
</form>

<h3>This is where the data is supposed to appear from getBulletAction()</h3>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: a) `document.write`? why? never use document.write unless you fully understand the consequences. b) `let bulletAction = form.bulletAction.value; let x = bulletAction; return x; ` why the `x` variable? why not just return `bulletAction`?

Comment: a form submit has a default action ... you'll need to prevent this default action ... using preventDefault - otherwise your page will simply re-load in this case

Comment: document.write was a quick way for me to test trying to pass my data out of the function.  I'm not getting anything out of my first function.

Comment: i'm not using submit as the input type though... does this apply to the button type as well ?

Comment: sorry, I saw submit, thought it was type=submit - my bad

Comment: updated my code to reflect returning the element array of the form data instead of pointing to the form field. However i'm still getting the same issue.  I am unable to return element[0].value to a variable out side of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing value in global variable when script loads(at the time when  was empty)

1. Create one global variable at the start of script
2. Change value of global variable **when user clicks submit button**
3. Use the global variable in another `function`

```js
var text = "";
function getBulletAction(form) {
 text = form[0].value; //first input element
 return form[0].value;
}
function myFunc(form){
  var inputText = getBulletAction(form);
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = getAction();
}
function getAction(){ //let's use global variable
 let action = text.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US');
 return action;
}
function alertMyGlobalVar(){
     alert(text);
}
```

```html
<form name="bulletForm" id="frmForm">
Write the action of your bullet:<br>
 <input type="text" name="bulletAction" value="" style="width: 30%;"/>
 <input type="button" name="submitType" value="Submit" onClick="myFunc(this.parentElement)" />
</form>
<button onclick="alertMyGlobalVar()">Current value of global variable</button><br>
<h id="log">This is where the data is supposed to appear from getBulletAction()</h3>
```

Comment: This is close to what i want, but the changes from getAction() are not returned update  the global variable.  I had to make getAction() take the argument from global scope: getAction(x), and modify the alertMyGlobalVar() to do what myFunc() was doing.    


function updateBullet(){
document.getElementById("log2).innerHTML = getAction(text)
}

Thank-you so much for straightening me out.